# QStandardItem object has no attribute findItems

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, treeview

Hello I am trying to oragnise multiples paths in one `treeview` but this code is not working

I got error like below :

```
AttributeError: 'QStandardItem' object has no attribute 'findItems'
its like QStandardItem do no have a function to find the item
```

do you have any idea

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTreeView, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class TreeViewExample(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("QTreeView Example")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.tree_view = QTreeView(self.central_widget)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.tree_view.setModel(self.model)

        # Replace this list with your own list of file paths
        file_paths = [
            "/home/user/documents/file1.txt",
            "/home/user/documents/folder1/file2.txt",
            "/home/user/documents/folder1/file3.txt",
            "/home/user/pictures/photo1.jpg",
            "/home/user/pictures/folder2/photo2.jpg",
        ]

        # Organize file paths in parent-child hierarchy
        self.organize_paths(file_paths)

        # Set up the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree_view)

    def organize_paths(self, file_paths):
        for path in file_paths:
            components = path.split("/")
            current_parent = None

            for component in components:
                print(component)
                item = self.get_or_create_item(component, parent=current_parent)
                current_parent = item

    def get_or_create_item(self, text, parent=None):
        items = parent.findItems(text) if parent else self.model.findItems(text)
        if items:
            return items[0]
        else:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
            if parent:
                parent.appendRow(item)
            else:
                self.model.appendRow(item)
            return item

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TreeViewExample()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: as for me `QStandardItem` is already a single item and it doesn't need `findItems()`. Maybe you should check if you get `QStandardItem` and skip `findItems()` or even skip rest of code. Or maybe `QStandardItem` needs different method - like `child()`

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: As the [QStandardItem documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html) clearly shows, there is no such `findItems()` function; where did you take that? It seems more like a classic example of AI failure (and, if that's the case, a further example of why generative AI shouldn't be used for coding, unless it's done under experienced guidance). Use [`QAbstractItemModel.match()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match) with appropriate flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QStandardItem` doesn't have `findItems()` so you have to run different code for `parent`.

You can use `for`-loop with `.rowCount()` to get every  `.child(row)` in `QStandardItem` and check `child.text() == text`

```py
    def get_or_create_item(self, text, parent=None):

        if parent:
            # find item for QStandardItem
            item = None
            
            for row in range(parent.rowCount()):
                child = parent.child(row)
                if child.text() == text:
                    item = child
                    break
                
            if item:
                return item
            else:
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
                parent.appendRow(item)
                return item
        else:
            # find items for model
            items = self.model.findItems(text)
            
            if items:
                return items[0]
            else:
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
                self.model.appendRow(item)
                return item
```

Result:

[image]

---

Full working code:

Because `path.split('/')` gives empty string as first element so I use `[1:]` to skip it in `components = path.split("/")[1:]`

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTreeView, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class TreeViewExample(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("QTreeView Example")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.tree_view = QTreeView(self.central_widget)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.tree_view.setModel(self.model)

        # Replace this list with your own list of file paths
        file_paths = [
            "/home/user/documents/file1.txt",
            "/home/user/documents/folder1/file2.txt",
            "/home/user/documents/folder1/file3.txt",
            "/home/user/pictures/photo1.jpg",
            "/home/user/pictures/folder2/photo2.jpg",
        ]

        # Organize file paths in parent-child hierarchy
        self.organize_paths(file_paths)

        # Set up the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree_view)

    def organize_paths(self, file_paths):
        for path in file_paths:
            components = path.split("/")[1:]
            current_parent = None

            for component in components:
                #print('component:', component)
                item = self.get_or_create_item(component, parent=current_parent)
                current_parent = item

    def get_or_create_item(self, text, parent=None):

        if parent:
            #print('add to parent:', text, parent)
            item = None
            
            # find item
            for row in range(parent.rowCount()):
                child = parent.child(row)
                #print('>> child:', child.text(), child)
                if child.text() == text:
                    item = child
                    break
                
            if item:
                #print('  parent return:', item)
                return item
            else:
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
                parent.appendRow(item)
                #print('  parent create:', text, item)
                return item
        else:
            #print('add to model:', text)
            items = self.model.findItems(text)
            
            if items:
                #print('  model return:', items[0])
                return items[0]
            else:
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
                self.model.appendRow(item)
                #print('  model create:', text, item)
                return item

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TreeViewExample()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 2):

Only QStandardItemModel provides a `findItems()` function, and it also has the important limitation of not allowing search within a specific parent, if not by manually iterating through each one of them looking for a match.

While the above may still be acceptable for simple situations (as shown in the [answer provided by furas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77603785/2001654)), if the path count becomes larger it's better to rely on the default search function of all Qt models, [`match()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match), which is also what QStandardItemModel internally does.

The benefit of that function is that it natively allows searching within non top-level items, making the whole process much faster. While for a few dozen items the result may be quite similar, when going beyond that amount the overall speed is at least doubled.

```py
    def organize_paths(self, file_paths):
        rootIndex = QModelIndex()
        rootItem = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        for path in file_paths:
            parent = rootIndex
            parentItem = rootItem
            for component in path.strip('/').split('/'):
                if self.model.rowCount(parent):
                    # parent has children, look for a match
                    match = self.model.match(
                        self.model.index(0, 0, parent), Qt.DisplayRole, 
                        component, flags=Qt.MatchExactly
                    )
                    if match:
                        # item already exists, make it the new parent
                        parent = match[0]
                        parentItem = self.model.itemFromIndex(parent)
                        continue

                # no existing children or match found, create the new
                # item and make it the new (possible) parent
                item = QStandardItem(component)
                parentItem.appendRow(item)
                parentItem = item
                parent = self.model.indexFromItem(item)
```

Comment: yesterday I saw your comment about `match()` and  I was going to ask if you will create answer which shows how to use `match()` :) Thanks.